# Folder not created using Hadoop Mapreduce code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to create a file with in "in" folder. but when i tried to run this in cluster i noticed that this "in" folder is not within hdfs.

why is it so?

Any thing wrong?

My Driver code is

```
    Path in = new Path("in");
    Path input = new Path("in/inputfile");
    BufferedWriter createinput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(input)));
```

According to this code a "in" folder and a file "inputfile" should be created in working directory of cluster  right?

Comment: Did you check for permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Path p = new Path(“hdfs://node1:50070/foo/bar”);
FileSystem fs = p.getFileSystem(conf);

DataOutputStream file = fs.create(p);

file.writeUTF(“hello\n”);

file.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use unix commands to create folder.

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir <paths>
```